# How to check if a EntityEntry is derived from BaseEntity<TKey> in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `BaseEntity<TKey>` with common audit properties for all entities,

**`BaseEntity<TKey>`**:

```cs
public class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; protected set; }

    public bool Active { get; protected set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; protected set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; protected set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedAt { get; protected set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; protected set; }
}
```

and a derived entities with different key, for example

**Derived Entities:**

```cs
public class Book : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Author : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookAuthor
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add created/updated user and time stamp details in my EF Core `SaveChangesAsync()`. But I'm not able to make this happen.

**Overrided `SaveChangesAsync()`:**

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{

    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    var user = "User Name";
    var entityEntries = ChangeTracker
                        .Entries()
                        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity<>
                                    && (e.State.Equals(EntityState.Added) || e.State.Equals(EntityState.Modified))
                                    && !e.Metadata.IsOwned());

    foreach (var entry in entityEntries)
    {
        entry.Property("ModifiedAt").CurrentValue = timestamp;
        entry.Property("ModifiedBy").CurrentValue = user;

        if (entry.State.Equals(EntityState.Added))
        {
            entry.Property("CreatedAt").CurrentValue = timestamp;
            entry.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = user;
            entry.Property("Active").CurrentValue = true;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}
```

How to check `e.Entity is BaseEntity<>` in my `LINQ` query? If I remove the condition and run; then `BookAuthor` will throw exception as they don't have audit properties. Please assist

Comment: Are you open to using reflection?

Comment: But will it be costly?

Comment: More costly than a simple type check using the `is` operator.

Comment: Using reflection, the following holds true: `typeof(BaseEntity<>) == typeof(Book).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what needs to be clear is that the base classes are not "common" in the way you describe.

if you have two derived classes

```
public class Book : BaseEntity<int>
public class Author : BaseEntity<Guid>
```

`BaseEntity<int>` and `BaseEntity<Guid>`  are actually two separate types. The two do not share a common base class and so there is no common type that both can be cast into other than object.  if you want the base class to be common then you would have to use  a separate approach.  Eg use a base class that does not take a generic parameter and have the TKey Id as an object.

or you have a common base class like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public bool Active { get; protected set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; protected set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; protected set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedAt { get; protected set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; protected set; }
}

public class BaseEntity<TKey> : BaseEntity
{
    public TKey Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

and then you can do the following:

```
var entityEntries = ChangeTracker
                    .Entries()
                    .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity
                                && (e.State.Equals(EntityState.Added) || 
e.State.Equals(EntityState.Modified))
                                && !e.Metadata.IsOwned());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and teaching. Respect Earned.